# Quickest way to prove irreduciblity?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Is there any quick way to show that $x^6-3$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_7$ without using rabin's test ?

Answer (score 2):

It's irreducible if a root generates the degree 6 extension $\mathbb{F}_{7^6}$

A relatively easy way to figure out what field that roots generate is that if $\alpha$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity, then the $m$-th roots of $\alpha$ are primitive $mn$-th roots of unity. So you just need to find the smallest extension capable of having a primitive $mn$-th root of unity.

Comment: Careful: You need all the prime factors of $m$ to also be prime factors  of $n$ (or some such criterion) for it to be so simple. For example, one of the third roots of an eighth root of unity is of order eight rather than of order $24$.

Comment: In case there was any doubt: this argument does work in the following sense. At least one of the $m$-th roots of $\alpha$ does have order $mn$. Sorry about possibly leaving that in doubt earlier due to my haste.